# Slightly confused with what function I should use with addEventListener in my Website

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I was trying something with JavaScript where I could make a background of moving stars on a blank canvas on HTML.

The background moves the stars depending on whether the user moves his mouse or not. It did work as intended, however I later decided to change its functionality by adding a mousepad-like box created using a  which would allow the background to move only when the mousepad is in focus. I tried doing this using addEventListener but it doesn't work. I think I might be calling the wrong function.

I tried doing the following at the start of my .js file :

```
const mousepad = document.querySelector('.mousepad');

mousepad.addEventListener('focus', render);
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Code:

```js
const STAR_COLOR = '#fff';
const STAR_SIZE = 3;
const STAR_MIN_SCALE = 0.2;
const OVERFLOW_THRESHOLD = 50;
const STAR_COUNT = (window.innerWidth + window.innerHeight) / 20;

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

let scale = 1, // device pixel ratio
  width,
  height;

let stars = [];

let pointerX,
  pointerY;

let velocity = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  tx: 0,
  ty: 0,
  z: 0.0005
};

let touchInput = false;

generate();
resize();
step();

window.onresize = resize;
canvas.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
canvas.ontouchmove = onTouchMove;
canvas.ontouchend = onMouseLeave;
document.onmouseleave = onMouseLeave;

function generate() {

  for (let i = 0; i < STAR_COUNT; i++) {
    stars.push({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: STAR_MIN_SCALE + Math.random() * (1 - STAR_MIN_SCALE)
    });
  }
}

function placeStar(star) {
  star.x = Math.random() * width;
  star.y = Math.random() * height;
}

function recycleStar(star) {
  let direction = 'z';

  let vx = Math.abs(velocity.x),
    vy = Math.abs(velocity.y);

  if (vx > 1 || vy > 1) {
    let axis;

    if (vx > vy) {
      axis = Math.random() < vx / (vx + vy) ? 'h' : 'v';
    } else {
      axis = Math.random() < vy / (vx + vy) ? 'v' : 'h';
    }

    if (axis === 'h') {
      direction = velocity.x > 0 ? 'l' : 'r';
    } else {
      direction = velocity.y > 0 ? 't' : 'b';
    }
  }

  star.z = STAR_MIN_SCALE + Math.random() * (1 - STAR_MIN_SCALE);

  if (direction === 'z') {
    star.z = 0.1;
    star.x = Math.random() * width;
    star.y = Math.random() * height;
  } else if (direction === 'l') {
    star.x = -OVERFLOW_THRESHOLD;
    star.y = height * Math.random();
  } else if (direction === 'r') {
    star.x = width + OVERFLOW_THRESHOLD;
    star.y = height * Math.random();
  } else if (direction === 't') {
    star.x = width * Math.random();
    star.y = -OVERFLOW_THRESHOLD;
  } else if (direction === 'b') {
    star.x = width * Math.random();
    star.y = height + OVERFLOW_THRESHOLD;
  }
}

function resize() {
  scale = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

  width = window.innerWidth * scale;
  height = window.innerHeight * scale;

  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  stars.forEach(placeStar);
}

function step() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  update();
  render();

  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

function update() {
  velocity.tx *= 0.96;
  velocity.ty *= 0.96;

  velocity.x += (velocity.tx - velocity.x) * 0.8;
  velocity.y += (velocity.ty - velocity.y) * 0.8;

  stars.forEach((star) => {

    star.x += velocity.x * star.z;
    star.y += velocity.y * star.z;

    star.x += (star.x - width / 2) * velocity.z * star.z;
    star.y += (star.y - height / 2) * velocity.z * star.z;
    star.z += velocity.z;

    // recycle when out of bounds
    if (star.x < -OVERFLOW_THRESHOLD || star.x > width + OVERFLOW_THRESHOLD || star.y < -OVERFLOW_THRESHOLD || star.y > height + OVERFLOW_THRESHOLD) {
      recycleStar(star);
    }
  });
}

function render() {
  stars.forEach((star) => {

    context.beginPath();
    context.lineCap = 'round';
    context.lineWidth = STAR_SIZE * star.z * scale;
    context.globalAlpha = 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.random();
    context.strokeStyle = STAR_COLOR;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(star.x, star.y);

    var tailX = velocity.x * 2,
      tailY = velocity.y * 2;

    // stroke() wont work on an invisible line
    if (Math.abs(tailX) < 0.1) tailX = 0.5;
    if (Math.abs(tailY) < 0.1) tailY = 0.5;

    context.lineTo(star.x + tailX, star.y + tailY);

    context.stroke();
  });
}

function movePointer(x, y) {
  if (typeof pointerX === 'number' && typeof pointerY === 'number') {

    let ox = x - pointerX,
      oy = y - pointerY;

    velocity.tx = velocity.tx + (ox / 8 * scale) * (touchInput ? 1 : -1);
    velocity.ty = velocity.ty + (oy / 8 * scale) * (touchInput ? 1 : -1);

  }

  pointerX = x;
  pointerY = y;
}


function onMouseMove(event) {
  touchInput = false;
  movePointer(event.clientX, event.clientY);
}

function onTouchMove(event) {
  touchInput = true;
  movePointer(event.touches[0].clientX, event.touches[0].clientY, true);
  event.preventDefault();
}


function onMouseLeave() {
  pointerX = null;
  pointerY = null;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at top right, rgba(84, 187, 115, 0.13), transparent), radial-gradient(circle at 20% 80%, rgba(41, 196, 255, 0.13), transparent)
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mousepad {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(41, 196, 255, 0.13);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Hide Scrollbar for aesthetic looks*/

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>

<div class="mousepad"></div>
```

Comment: If you only want to call `render()` when the event happens, don't call it from `step()` as well. But I'm not sure that's what you really want. What you probably need to do is set a global flag when the user clicks on the trackpad, and clear it when they release. Then the other functions can check the variable, and not do anything when it's not set.

Comment: When I remove it from step(), the code would not work because step acts as a helper method. I tried it but did not work.

Comment: I understand that, that's why I said it's probably not what you really want to do. The rest of the comment is more to the point.

Comment: Do you understand that event listeners just run once, when the event happens? They don't represent a state that happens continuously, like being focused on an element. The event listener will run at the moment that the user changes focus to the element. That's why you need to set a variable, it exists continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, You only have an issue with the focus event on a div element?

In order to receive a focus on a div you need to specify a `tabindex`for this div.

Like this : `<div class="mousepad" tabindex="0"></div>`.
Keep in mind that focusin bubbles, while focus does not.

```js
        window.addEventListener("load",onLoadHandler);
        function onLoadHandler(e){
            const mousepad = document.querySelector('.mousepad');
            mousepad.addEventListener('focus', startRender);
            mousepad.addEventListener('blur', stopRender);
        }
        function startRender(e){
            e.target.innerHTML="focus in";
        }
        function stopRender(e){
            e.target.innerHTML="focus out";
        }
```

```css
        .mousepad{
            width: 700px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: rgba(41, 196, 255, 0.13);
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin: auto;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="mousepad" tabindex="0">
        Click in and out the div to focus in our out
    </div>
```

You can also use :

```
  mousepad.addEventListener('focusin', startRender);
  mousepad.addEventListener('focusout', stopRender);
```

I hope this can help.

Have a nice day.

Nicolas.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got my website to work. Though, I tried using a flag variable as @Barmar has suggested and it did work. But this is a better method in my opinion. Less code.

Comment: @ChaitanyaChaurasia I'm happy for you. I like this effect! Mark it as solved if it is, please. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching this `mousemove` event listener. You can see a example below:

```js
document.getElementById("background").addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
  let element = document.getElementById("background");
  element.innerHTML = parseInt(element.innerHTML) + 1
})
```

```css
#background {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">1</div>
```